# Is it possible to do create a generic Session.QueryOver<T>?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Out of curiosity is it possible to do something like this using NHibernate 3?

```
public IQueryable<T> FindAll<T>()
{
   return Session.QueryOver<T>().List().AsQueryable();
}
```

I get a compilation error saying something like...

The Type T must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter T.

I was wondering if I could create an extension method to Session.QueryOver to handle a generic type.

I could replace this using something like

```
return Session.CreateCriteria(typeof (T)).List<T>().AsQueryable();
```

But was keen to use the features of the query api. Any ideas? maybe missing something obvious!!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing a restriction on `T`:

```
public IQueryable<T> FindAll<T>() where T : class
{
   return Session.QueryOver<T>().List().AsQueryable();
}
```

`where T : class` defines that `T` has to be a reference type. (As the compile error demanded, apperently `QueryOver<T>` is restricted to reference type). If a type parameter has constraints applied to it, any generic method using this method with a generic parameter of its own has to apply similar constraints.

For a complete overview of generic type parameter constraints, see [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970(v=VS.80).aspx).

Comment: I knew I missed something obvious!